# Find a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ not of the form $H\oplus K$ for some $H\le \Bbb Z_4, K\le \Bbb Z_2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

This is Exercise 8.28 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*.

**Answers that use only methods from the textbook prior to the exercise are preferred.**

Here $G_1\oplus G_2$ is the *external direct product* of  $G_1$ by $G_2$.

Here $G_1\le G_2$ means $G_1$ is a *subgroup or equal to* the group $G_2$.

### The Question:

> Find a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ not of the form $H\oplus K$ for some $H\le \Bbb Z_4, K\le \Bbb Z_2$.

*Thoughts:*

I must confess: I cheated here a little bit by looking up the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2$. But notice the difference in notation! I think in terms of just plain old *direct products* (because aren't internal and external direct products equivalent? Yes! But this is not established in the textbook yet; indeed, the former is not even mentioned at this point).

It appears to me to be a trick question. [Here are the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2$.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_direct_product_of_Z4_and_Z2) Where is the subgroup of the desired form?

My guess is that there's some technical aspect of *external* direct products that is being emphasised here.

Please help :)

Comment: What does "internal direct product" mean? Are you assuming $\mathbb Z_4,\mathbb Z_2$ are subgroups of some larger group?

Comment: Sorry, @Wojowu: I got them the wrong way around! Hang on a second while I edit the question . . .

Comment: Also, the symmetric groups by Cayley's theorem, I would imagine, @Wojowu.

Comment: There aren't too many subgroups of $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_2$. Why not just list them all and check which ones are of the given form?

Comment: Internal direct products are mentioned in Section 9 of the textbook, @Wojowu; I'm on Section 8.

Comment: That's my problem, @Arthur: I have looked at a list of the subgroups. I can't tell which are of the given form from the list I linked to. I suppose it's just a matter of "shut up and calculate", then, huh?

Comment: @Shaun In a small case like this, "shut up and calculate" might be my preferred approach. But there are some theoretical considerations which may help it go faster. For instance, if a subgroup is of the form $H\oplus K$ and contains $(a,b)$, then it must also contain $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$. So taking an element of the form $(a,b)$ with $a,b\neq0$ and looking at the cyclic group generated by that element would be my first attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyclic group generated by $(1,1)$ fits. It maps surjectively under both projections, but it is not the whole group, so you cannot write it as the direct product of two subgroups.